# WSO2 Identity Server SAML Error encrypting XMLObject at Example Travelocity

Tags: wso2, server, identity

When setting in the sample app:  Travelocity.properties

```
#Specify if SAM LAssertion element is encrypted
SAML.EnableAssertionEncryption=true
```

And also tick the Identity server configuration option:

```
Enable Assertion Encryption [ticked] 
Certificate Alias: wso2carbon
```

I receive the following error at the server log:

> Error at Log:  2015-05-05 15:56:10,282    Error encrypting XMLObject

Without the encryption feature enabled, the SAML authentication flow with the Travelocity sample code starts working.

Hints are welcome how to fix this issue.

Regards, 
Claude

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are working on the installed java runtime for the first time. I am using ubuntu 14. The same problem came to me. For me it worked in the following way.

```
1. Download the respective files according to your runtime from here.
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html
2. Extract the folder you downloaded. There will be two .jar files.
3. For ubuntu you can run echo $JAVA_HOME to find the java home. Copy above jar files into {JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security. You may need sudo access depending on you JAVA_HOME location. If so run the following from the location you extracted the zip file.
   cp local_policy.jar /{JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security
   cp US_export_policy.jar /{JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security
   There should be only one slash (/) at /{JAVA_HOME}. 
4. Restart wso2 identity server again and retry the procedure to login to travelocity.com
```

Hope this will fix your issue.